# Restore LINE chat from Google Drive

Tags: restore, google-drive, line

I always back up all [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(software)) chats regularly to google drive. When line is re-installed I tried to restore the chat but it says "No chat history backup found". Does anyone know how to deal with this?